# What would be Openshift REST API equivalent of a process template command

Tags: rest, api, automation, openshift, continuous-delivery

I am automating some continuous delivery processess that use openshift 3.5. They work fine from a command line, but I can hardly find any documentation of how the `oc` commands map to the [OCP REST API](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/rest_api/index.html). I've figured out how talk to the API and use what it directly offers. For example, I have a line:

```
oc process build-template -p APPLICATION_NAME=worldcontrol -n openshift | oc create -f - -n conspiracyspace
```

That takes a template named "build-template" from "openshift" namespace and processes it, piping the resulting definition to build a few objects like application image, into another namespace. I would appreciate an example of how this could be expressed in http request terms.

**edit**

Following @Graham's hint, here is what I got. First request is getting the contents of the template:

```
curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: oc/v3.5.5.15 (linux/amd64) openshift/4b5f317" -H "Authorization: Bearer ...." -H "Accept: application/json, */*" https://example.com/oapi/v1/namespaces/openshift/templates/build-template
```

Then apparently the oc client expands the parameters internally, and feeds the result into the POST:

```
curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: oc/v3.5.5.15 (linux/amd64) openshift/4b5f317" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer ...." https://example.com/oapi/v1/namespaces/openshift/processedtemplates
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the `oc` command with the option `--loglevel=10`. This will show you what REST API calls it makes underneath and thus you can work out what you need to do to do the same thing with just the REST API. Do note that certain things may be partly done in the `oc` client, rather than delegating to a REST API endpoint call.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, and at the very end of the output from the CLI, I saw this:

```
service "trade4-65869977-9d56-49a5-afa2-4a547df82d5c" created
deploymentconfig "trade4-65869977-9d56-49a5-afa2-4a547df82d5c" created
```

When piping to `oc create -f -`, then, the CLI must be inspecting the resulting template and creating each object in the objects array. No evidence of those calls were outputted to my command window, other than the two "created" statements.

So to fully automate this through the REST API, we would still need to parse that objects array returned by `processtemplates` and POST to the appropriate endpoints, correct?

Comment: You are better off asking a new question, not asking one in an answer to an existing question. In that question provide more complete details of what you are doing so far and what you need.